# Drag 360 view camera in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm working at 360 Image in Unity. The below code is working fine, but I have to use both my fingers to drag camera around.

How can I use a single touch to move around? And I also want to click on objects while moving.

```
public class DragCamera : MonoBehaviour {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR

        bool isDragging = false;
        float startMouseX;
        float startMouseY;
        Camera cam;
        void Start () {

            cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        }
        void Update () {

            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && !isDragging )
            {                

                isDragging = true;

                // save the mouse starting position
                startMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
                startMouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;
            }
            else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1) && isDragging)
            {                
                // set the flag to false
                isDragging = false;
            }
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {

            if(isDragging)
            {

                float endMouseX = Input.mousePosition.x;
                float endMouseY = Input.mousePosition.y;

                //Difference (in screen coordinates)
                float diffX = endMouseX - startMouseX;
                float diffY = endMouseY - startMouseY;


                float newCenterX = Screen.width / 2 + diffX;
                float newCenterY = Screen.height / 2 + diffY;

                Vector3 LookHerePoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(newCenterX, newCenterY, cam.nearClipPlane));

                //Make our camera look at the "LookHerePoint"
                transform.LookAt(LookHerePoint);

                //starting position for the next call
                startMouseX = endMouseX;
                startMouseY = endMouseY;
            }
        }

        #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add real touch support to your app.

I don’t know if you actually understand the script you got.

It’s a mess. I’ll fix it for you.

```
public class DragCamera : MonoBehaviour {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR

        bool isDragging = false;
        float startMouseX;
        float startMouseY;
        Camera cam;
        void Start () {

            cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        }
        void Update () {

            if(Input.touchCount > 0 && !isDragging )
            {                

                isDragging = true;

                // save the mouse starting position
                startMouseX = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x;
                startMouseY = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;
            }
            else if(Input.touchCount == 0 && isDragging)
            {                
                // set the flag to false
                isDragging = false;
            }
        }

        void LateUpdate()
        {

            if(isDragging)
            {

                float endMouseX = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x;
                float endMouseY = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;

                //Difference (in screen coordinates)
                float diffX = endMouseX - startMouseX;
                float diffY = endMouseY - startMouseY;


                float newCenterX = Screen.width / 2 + diffX;
                float newCenterY = Screen.height / 2 + diffY;

                Vector3 LookHerePoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(newCenterX, newCenterY, cam.nearClipPlane));

                //Make our camera look at the "LookHerePoint"
                transform.LookAt(LookHerePoint);

                //starting position for the next call
                startMouseX = endMouseX;
                startMouseY = endMouseY;
            }
        }

        #endif
    }
}
```

Please note this code is awful and messy it’s recommended not the use it. It’s untested which means it may or may not work.

I’m just here to fix up what you got.

If you want to learn more about mobile input in Unity read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html)

Good luck